# Is pthread_self() expensive?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, ubuntu-12.04

Is `pthread_self()` expensive on `ubuntu 12.04` ?
Does it uses a system call?

I want to call `pthread_self()` each time a thread wrote to log, so I'll know which thread wrote to log and mention it on the log. All threads write to the same log file.

Comment: Try it and find out. It should be very easy to write a test program to call it, say, 100,000 times and measure its performance. I would guess it's fairly cheap, but I don't know for sure. You can use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find out what syscalls it makes, if any. For bonus points, come back here and post an answer to your own question with what you found out... I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: No, it's O(1), sans syscall, and very cheap... copying the thread id from a specific structure that each thread has as a known offset, with a register that should always be holding the segment.  See http://www.unix.com/programming/137683-calling-pthread_self-ubuntu-expensive.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As dvnrrs suggested, I wrote the following `code`:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

            pthread_self();
    }
 }
```

And ran it with `time code`

and got:

> real    0m0.001s
>   user    0m0.000s
>   sys     0m0.001s

Running the loop for 10000000 times gave me:

> real    0m0.045s
>   user    0m0.044s
>   sys     0m0.000s

I ran it with `strace -c -ttT ./code` and got

> % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
>
> ---
>
> -nan    0.000000           0         2           read
>     -nan    0.000000           0         3           open
>     -nan    0.000000           0         3           close
>     -nan    0.000000           0         3           fstat
>     -nan    0.000000           0        11           mmap
>     -nan    0.000000           0         5           mprotect
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           munmap
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           brk
>     -nan    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1         1 access
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           execve
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
>     -nan    0.000000           0         2         1 futex
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
>     -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
>
> ---
>
> 100.00    0.000000                    40         2 total

Answer (score 5):

You can check the source code here: https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.19/pthread__self_8c_source.html

As you can see from the link above, pthread_self() returns THREAD_SELF, which is defined as a simple assembly `movl` instruction. No system calls there. Of course, this is implementation defined. The link above refers to glibc library.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `pthread_self()` results in a syscall, it will be a relatively cheap one since it will simply look up the result. It will definitely not grab any locks (because the value you need is constant), or do anything else which is a huge performance burner. I expect something below one microsecond, but I may be wrong.

If you call it right after a `write()` call, you shouldn't need to worry about the performance of `pthread_self()`, because the time required for the `write()` will be much longer. After all, `write()` does need to grab locks to ensure POSIX semantics (i. e. that the written data becomes visible to all other processes *immediately*).

If your experiments show you that `pthread_self()` indeed performs a syscall, you can easily cache its return value in a `thread_local` global variable which you set right at the start of the pthread (the `thread_local` keyword is part of the C/C++11 standards if I'm not much mistaken).